# How long did Kara live on Earth before becoming Supergirl?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In *Supergirl (2015)* TV series, Kara left Krypton when she was teenager (or, maybe pre-teen). Then, she got stuck in Phantom Zone and didn't age until after she crashed on Earth.

When she became Supergirl (the day she saved the airplane or the day her boss named her), she was grown up. It's simply visible.

But, Kryptonians age at slower rate under yellow sun. This canon also supports this because Kara has super healing capability in the TV show (meaning higher resistance against ageing processes). How long did she live on Earth before becoming Supergirl?

I tried to compare it with the age of her human sister, but it didn't help because her sister's age wasn't visible. When Kara met her, she was already grown up and when Kara became Supergirl, she could be in her 20s, 30s, 40s, 50s (Anti-aging creams in case of latter ages; can't be 60s because she had an active job).

Comment: I think there is a difference between, growing and aging. I don't believe the Kent's were stuck with a teenage Clark for decades. Unless you count Smallville as cannon.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. Are you saying that 33-year-old Chyler Lee would be believable as a 50 year old, but 60 is out because otherwise she would be retired?

Comment: @Jonah You can ignore that bit from the question. The question would still be valid.

Comment: Is it mentioned in the series that Kryptonians age at a slower rate? I don't remember this mentioned in *Man of Steel* (though *Man of Steel* and *SuperGirl* are, AFAIK, different DC universes).

Comment: @Taladris An episode of Justice League showed the future. Bruce Wayne was out of commission due to old age, but Clark Kent wasn't.

Comment: @SS-3: thanks for commenting. Are they supposed to be in the same universe? AFAIK, the different DC movies/TV shows are not clearly in the same universe. Except obviously The Flash/Arrow/Legend of Tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says it [right there in the pilot](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=297&t=18484)

> My name is Kara Zor-El. 24 years ago my planet, Krypton, was in
>   serious peril. My cousin, Kal-El, was sent to a planet called Earth.
>   for his own safety and protection You may know his story. The story
>   you don't know is that I was sent to protect him.

and

> When I arrived, I
>   was still a 13-year-old girl.

**Since she's narrating from an in-universe perspective, she must have been living on Earth for approx 11 years.**

Her personal age is confirmed by the show's [official blurb](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/01/22/supergirl-melissa-benoist)

> *”Born on the planet Krypton, Kara Zor-El escaped amid its destruction years ago. Since arriving on Earth, she’s been hiding the powers she shares with her famous cousin. **But now at age 24, she decides to embrace her superhuman abilities** and be the hero she was always meant to be.”*

Comment: Oops. 13 + 9 doesn't equal 24

Answer (score 1):

[Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114070/30726) used to be perfectly correct and clear -- and it still is (for the most part) after the airing of the Season 2 Finale, where we get this nice little title card:

[image: 35 years ago... The Day Krypton died]

The timeline given by Valorum's answer (which is of course directly quoting the show) can only be maintained, if the "24 years ago" bit is narrated by Kara from the temporal perspective that is actually shown at that moment, meaning that she was stuck in the Phantom Zone for 24 years as a 13 year old (imagine her reading a diary entry from back then to us before she starts going on about her job at the then shown (and then "now") of fall 2015).

Since the show ran for two full seasons after the first episode quote, Kara has now been on Earth for **11 years** and is 24/25, but at the time she became Supergirl she had been on Earth 2 fewer years, meaning she would have been on Earth before becoming Supergirl for **9 years**.

In essence, the whole timeline is probably yet another example of (**!! Warning! TVTropes Link !!**) [Writers Cannot Do Math](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WritersCannotDoMath) - or retconning themselves for no apparent reason.

**Edit:** The episode *Midvale* (3x06) shows Kara (and Alex) still in High School, but clearly older than we have seen in the past. Jeremiah is already gone and Alex resentful of Kara being there at all. The episode also includes this:

[image: supergirl_3x06_10yearsago]

So if Krpyton's destruction was 35 years before, and Kara and Alex were both clearly still teenagers 10 years before Season 3, she must have been in the Phantom Zone longer than a decade.

She states in the *Pilot* (1x01) that her

> cousin was here two dozen years before me.

In 2x01 Winn fanboys over Superman being

> 12 years older than Kara, right?

All of that makes sense if and only if Kara was in fact stuck in the Phantom Zone for 24 years as a 13 year old.

That would make 23/24 when coming out as Supergirl, and 26/27 at the time of Midvale (and 16/17 in the Flashback, although probably at the younger end of the scale since Alex is older [biologically if not chronologically] and still in high school too).